# Filter combobox based on another combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, dataview

I have zero problems getting this to work in a windows form and I can do this with jquery. For some reason it just won't work with C# & asp.net.

Three comboboxes on a webpage:

```
Specialty
Location
Department
```

I have a dataview that contains data from a db. I have all three bound to the same dataview, dv. The dv contains "specialty", "location", and "department" columns.

When I select a specialty I want to filter the DataView to only show those specialties. Each combobox should only display those rows.

```
protected void SpecialtyList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("department_specialty = '{0}'", SpecialtyList.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

AutoPostBack is True, when the event fires nothing filters. Am I crazy or overlooking something? My page has a catch for post backs so it's not re-initializing the data or resetting itself to default.

Comment: One thought is that this could probably be done in JavaScript on the client to save posting back to the server every time you change the filter. It sounds like the unfiltered dataset will be fetched initially anyway.

Comment: The combo box you're trying to filter, is it bound to `dv` (which I assume is a `DataView`) or is it bound to the `DataTable`?

Comment: I believe you need to set the list back to the filtered results. it will not take affect straight away.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post enough code - insufficient data to diagnose.

1. Can you attach a debugger and set a breakpoint in SpecialtyList_SelectedIndexChanged() to verify that it is getting called?
2. Can you post the full code, or at least the parts relevant to binding / populating the data?

Most common problem (I have seen) for this: doing the DataBind() on every load. When you rebind the data you lose the context for IndexChanged events, etc. You said you are not reinitializing the data in postbacks, but are you sure that you are not rebinding the data?

Try this:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
  SpecialtyList.DataBind();
}
```

You may also need to rebind the DataView after changing RowFilter:

```
protected void SpecialtyList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("department_specialty = '{0}'", SpecialtyList.SelectedValue.ToString());
    dv.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I figured it out.

The DataView was created inside if (!isPostBack) of the page load event. Once I moved it outside of that the data was there. 

Silly me thinking I could rely on ASP to maintain the data like a session.